# Accented characters displaying incorrectly in HTML

Tags: html, utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a collection of .htm documents that have been scraped from across the web.

When I open them in a text editor (in this case Notepad), any accented characters display incorrectly, with question marks,like so :

[image: accents displayed as question marks]

When I render the document in Firefox/any other browser the result is the same.

How can I fix this? What is likely to be the issue here?

Comment: Is it saved as UTF8?

Comment: @Scimonster How can I check this please? :)

Comment: If you are not accounting for encoding type differences when scraping various websites, you have your answer right there. If the encoding is explicitly declared it will be a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` of the page, otherwise you'll need to detect it with some software.

Comment: Use notepad ++ you can see encode menu when you open your file :)